# CKEditor and asp.net

Tags: ckeditor, asp.net-4.0

I am using CKEditor on my page. It is working fine except when I post back. I am getting this error:

`A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (ctl00$MainContent$txtDesc="<p>
&nbsp;</p>`

I am using this code to put CKEditor value into textbox on `OnClientClick` event of submit button:

```
function getEditorValue(){
    var editor=$("#<%= txtDesc.ClientID%>").ckeditorGet();
    editor.updateElement();
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `ValidateRequest="False"` in your `<% @Page` declaration.

Comment: I forgot to mention I'm using ASP.net 4.0 so I have to put `<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />` also in `web.config`.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried setting the htmlEncodeOutput property?

```
> CKEDITOR.replace('#<%= txtDesc.ClientID%>', {
>  htmlEncodeOutput: true });
```

This should encode the output and you should be able to avoid setting the requestValidationMode.

Documentation for it is here: [ckEditor documentation](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.htmlEncodeOutput)